# Making Postgres SQL minimal size. How?

Tags: database, postgresql, installation, portability

I want to cut Postgres to its minimal size for purpose of including just database function with my application. I'm using Portable Postgres found on internet.
Any suggestions what I can delete from Postgres installation which is not needed for normal database use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete all the standalone tools in /bin - it can all be done with psql. Keep anything that starts wth pg_, postgres and initdb.

You can probably delete a bunch of conversions in lib/ (the some_and_some.so) files, but probably not until after you've initdb'ed. And be careful not to delete one you'll be using at some point - they are dynamically loaded so you won't notice until a client connects with a different encoding for example.

But note that this probably won't get you much - on my system with debug enabled etc, the binaries take 17Mb. The clean data directory *with no data at all in it* takes 33Mb, about twice as much. Which you will need if you're going to be able to use your database..

Comment: That's debugging symbols - you can remove that, too, unless you want the ability to debug a crash.